# Bootstrap classes causing footer contents to not load completely until hovered

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, footer

I have an element with social media icons inside in the footer of my website.  I am using bootstrap col classes to position the element.  When I load the page an icon and the element borders are not visible until I hover over them.  I believe it has to do with some col classes, as when I remove them, it works fine.  FireFox and edge do not seem to have the problem, just chrome.  It has left me scratching my head.

here is the link to my site http://www.davidsandersdesigns.com/
and here is my footer html

```
<!--Footer-->
        <div class='container-fluid'>
            <div class='row'><!--Mobile-->
                <div id='bottom_doubleArrow' class='bottom_doubleArrow col-xs-6 col-sm-5 hidden-md hidden-lg col-xs-offset-5 col-sm-offset-5'></div>
            </div>
            <footer class='row'>
                <div id='footer_logo' class='footer_logo col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-md-offset-1'></div>
                <!--Problem Element--><div class='footerIcon_container hidden-xs hidden-sm col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-md-offset-7 col-lg-offset-8'>
                    <a>
                      <div class='mail_icon'></div>
                    </a>
                    <a>
                        <div class='linkedIn_icon'></div>
                    </a>
                    <a>
                        <div class='facebook_icon'></div>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div id='footer_doubleArrow' class='footer_doubleArrow hidden-xs hidden-sm col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-md-offset-10 col-lg-offset-10'></div><!--Desktop-->
            </footer>
        </div>
```

Here are the css classes that have to do with this element.

```
 .footerIcon_container {
  top: 20px;
  height: 90px;
  border-left: 1px solid white;
  border-right: 1px solid white; }

/* line 100, C:/Users/Frederick/Documents/Web Editing/Projects/Portfolio   site/build 2000/sass/partials/pages/mainPage/_footer.scss */
.mail_icon {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-image: url("../images/email_icon.svg");
  height: 40px;
  width: 55px;
  top: 25px;
  transition: opacity 300ms; }

   /* line 111, C:/Users/Frederick/Documents/Web Editing/Projects/Portfolio site/build 2000/sass/partials/pages/mainPage/_footer.scss */
.linkedIn_icon {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-image: url("../images/linkedin_icon.svg");
  height: 40px;
  width: 55px;
  top: 25px;
  transition: opacity 300ms; }

  /* line 122, C:/Users/Frederick/Documents/Web Editing/Projects/Portfolio site/build 2000/sass/partials/pages/mainPage/_footer.scss */
.facebook_icon {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-image: url("../images/facebook_icon.svg");
  height: 40px;
  width: 55px;
  top: 25px;
  transition: opacity 300ms; }
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a strange one. I added the following style in inspector and it seem to resolve the problem:

```
.footerIcon_container > a {
    display: block;
}
```

As to why it's happening - I'm not entirely sure to be honest!

EDIT - I also noticed that the `<div>`'s within the anchor elements are being floated, as so:

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=www.davidsandersdesigns.com" target="_blank">
    <div class="facebook_icon"></div>
</a>
```

CSS:

```
.facebook_icon {
    float: left;
}
```

When you inspect the wrapping `<a>` element, you'll notice that it has no height (it's collapsed). I added a clearfix class to the wrapping `<a>` as so:

```
<a class="clearfix" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=www.davidsandersdesigns.com" target="_blank">
```

This reinstated the height of the wrapping element (I did the same with the other social icons too.

I also experimented with removing the `float: left` from the inner `div`'s entirely, so remove it from this class as well as the other social classes too:

.facebook_icon {
   <strike>float: left;</strike>
}

You can then add `float: left` to the wrapping `<a>`'s as so:

```
.footerIcon_container > a {
    float: left;
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

Upon further inspection, I noticed that both the linkedIn and mail icons had the following styles applied in your styles.css file:

```
.linkedIn_icon {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}
```

The above is on line 477, the below for the mail icon is on line 464:

```
.mail_icon {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    background-image: url("../images/logo1.svg");
    height: 90%;
}
```

A lot of these styles are overriden, but there's a couple that aren't which seem to be the reason the other icons display... It seems that this is what is making the other icons appears, and the facebook one not. I advise amending the linkedIn one as follows so it also includes Facebook:

```
.linkedIn_icon, .facebook_icon {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}
```

Again, this seemed to work for me...

Comment: yea I do not have a clue.  Thank you for your answer but I still cannot get it resolved.

Comment: @DavidSanders, no problem I'll try and take another look at some point and will let you kow if i find anything!

Comment: Have you had anytime to look over this?

Comment: @DavidSanders, Sure did, please see revised answer as its too big to put in a comment! Again, this worked for me but it may be different when the page is reloaded...

Comment: Thank you for your time but this still does not seem to work.  I did update all of those styles in the site but it did not fix the problem.

Comment: Wow, this one really is giving you some grief, haha!!! Think I've got it this time, check EDIT 2!

Comment: @DavidSanders, did you get a chance to look at my revised edit - Edit 2?

Comment: not yet, I am going to look at it tomorrow, been a crazy week!

Comment: still know luck.  I  re did the footer a little and thought It was an overflow problem but it is still doing the same thing.